# Why is Eevee giving low res animation output?

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, resolution

**First off,** I wanted to make a HUD in blender. I thought it was better to use Eevee for its bloom effect. I can get single frames render at high res but IDK why the animation looks all pixeled..

---

[image: Rendered **IMAGE** in Eevee]

This is the rendered image and it looks pretty good. But the animation video is really low res[image: Pixelated video]
If you noticed you can see the pixelated retro sort of look. The rendered image at first is 1.08MBs. But the rendered video is 0.88MBs. I don't why this is happening..

---

They are the exact frame but why does the rendered video looks so crappy?? Anyone please help, thank you!!

Comment: Strongly recommend to only use image format in Blender. You will keep more control if you got an image file rather than video file.

Answer (score 3):

Set your video quality to high or lossless. A Bloom effect with dark and redbackground is really bad for image compressing method. Which tend to output a bad resolution or the image if the size of the file did not change.

[image]

If you want to make video like a professional artist, you might want to check out how image are stored in each format like jpeg, png, bmp, gif, h.264, h.265 and so on. (Notice that I did not mention mkv and mpeg(mp4) because they are container which work as a directory.)

And you might want to save your video in "Image" format to preserve the best quality while editing video sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Set the video quality output to constant bitrate, and just turn the bitrate + maximum up to 10,000, this works for me